# how to retrieve the entire data from firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to retrieve the entire data from firebase database?

[image]

```
ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        info info = dataSnapshot.getValue(info.class);
        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        tw_mail.setText(info.email);
        tw_Address.setText(info.address);
        tw_fact.setText(info.fact);
        tw_ownername.setText(info.ownername);
        tw_phone.setText(info.phone);
        tw_pin.setText(info.pin);
        tw_rent.setText(info.rent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Toast.makeText(locatepg.this, "Failed to load post.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};

mDatabase.addValueEventListener(postListener);
```

Comment: How is `mDatabase` defined?

Answer (score 0):

Just call [DatabaseReference.getRoot()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.html#getRoot())

```
firebaseDatabase.getRoot().addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        System.out.println(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()); // These are all your roots
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: i am getting all the values..but i am not knowing how to print the values?can you plz help me sir

Comment: Well, `dataSnapshot.getValue()` will give you a HashMap of your roots, you can iterate on it

Answer (score -2):

Please you have to set the child you want to retrieve data from it like this:

- First set your database reference.
- second select your child.

  ```
  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("user").child(getUid())        
            .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                 }
                @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
              Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"database error",
                      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
      });
  ```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. OP wants the whole firebase database to be retrieved. Specifying a child won't apply.